# PyQt4: QPixmap signals?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, signals-slots, qpixmap

Where can I find a list of the signals emitted by QPixmap, with descriptions? I looked in the official docs and I also googled "pyqt4 qpixmap signals" but I couldn't find anything.

I need this because I need to change the image displayed when the mouse hovers over the QPixmap. I was hoping to simply connect a function to a "hover" or "mouseover" signal, but I can't find such a thing.

A more general question: In the future, if I want to find a list of the signals emitted by a certain class, where can I find this information?

Answer (score 1):

The [QPixmap class](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html) does not define any signals. Only subclasses of [QObject](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qobject.html) can define signals, and QPixmap is not a subclass of QObject. The Qt documentation provides a section listing the signals for every class that defines them (e.g. [QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#signals)).

To track mouse movements, you must monitor the relevant system [events](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html) which are sent to the widget used to display the pixmap. One way to do this is to install an [event-filter](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters) on the display widget, and handle its [enter](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#enterEvent) and [leave](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#leaveEvent) events.

Here's a simple demo that shows how to do that:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.pixmap1 = QtGui.QPixmap('image1.jpg')
        self.pixmap2 = QtGui.QPixmap('image2.jpg')
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap1)
        self.label.installEventFilter(self)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

    def eventFilter(self, widget, event):
        if widget is self.label:
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Enter:
                self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap2)
            elif event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Leave:
                self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap1)
        return super(Window, self).eventFilter(widget, event)  

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 200, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```